# Unable to write columns using Google Sheets C# API

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use the c# Google Sheets API for inputting information into my Google Sheets via the code below, but it is only inputting as rows and I would like to input it as columns instead. Is there a way to do this?

```
valueRange.Values = new List<IList<object>> { objectList };
appendRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(valueRange, SpreadsheetId, range);
appendRequest.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
appendResponse = appendRequest.Execute();
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you what to accomplish? The [append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) method is for adding rows, not columns. Do you want to add the values to the first empty column instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code in the below. Seems your valueRange.Values convert is incorrect.

```
public static AppendValuesResponse InsertColumnLine(this SheetsService service, string spreadsheetId, string range, params object[] columnValues)
{
    // convert columnValues to columList
    var columList = columnValues.Select(v => new List<object> { v });

    // Add columList to values and input to valueRange
    var values = new List<IList<object>>();
    values.AddRange(columList.ToList());
    var valueRange = new ValueRange()
    {
        Values = values
    };

    // Create request and execute
    var appendRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(valueRange, spreadsheetId, range);
    appendRequest.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
    return appendRequest.Execute();
}
```

Use the extension `InsertColumnLine` method.

```
// Sample!A1 => Sample is workseet name, A1 cell feild
_sheetsService.InsertColumnLine(_chickenOptions.Debug.SpreadSheetId, "Sample!A1", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

See the result. I hope it will help you.
[image]